# Safe authentication in PHP

Tags: php, security

I'm building an API where unauthorized access can be denied along the lines of:

```
$APIKey = $_POST['API Key'];
if (!verifyAPIKey($APIKey)) {
    http_response_code(401);
    exit();
}
```

Assuming `verifyAPIKey()` is robust, is there a way an attacker could post data other than a valid API key which would evaluate the if condition to true and bypass this authentication step?

Comment: Post the code of `verifyAPIKey`

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I was really asking is assuming that `verifyAPIKey` can only return true with a valid API key or false without one, is there still a way to skip the if block? I suppose I should have said "Given some arbitary if  statement in PHP is there a technique hackers could use to skip it?" Like is there a way to hack if(1!=1){do something}?

Answer (score 2):

REST-full API's work on something called a [handshake](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjzmsfU9ZHQAhVsK8AKHXsrBlcQFggpMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHandshaking&usg=AFQjCNGwodKk_QBARPGcSv8zVY-7NzsAIQ&sig2=jG6xZTy6lM7Xw33H7UEd4g&bvm=bv.137904068,d.d24), so where security is concerned, we must ensure we are using SSL encryption in the data transfer.

When we talk about an *API Key* we're really saying a **random** but **unique** string (token) for that single user to gather data across domains ([CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)).

---

> Assuming verifyAPIKey() is robust

This isn't a pre-defined function in PHP. To include a 'robust' infastructure to API tokens, you would need a set of instructions.

- Client requesting data uses a unique token and return URI ->
- Client redirects user to your sandbox with this information ->
- User allows client access and Client recieves a seperate unique token ->
- Client creates a request with that token to an endpoint to then get the data

Really, the *hack* here would be an [Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) when you're querying your database for them tokens. However, not to worry because SO has plenty of resoucres on [securing queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

---

A simple example of this context would look something like this:

```
class Endpoint {

    private $Token;

    public function setToken($token) {
        $this->Token = $token;
        return $this;
    }

    public function isToken() {
        $smpt = (new Database)->Prepare('SQL HERE');
        $smpt->execute([$token]);
        return empty($smpt->fetch()[0]) ? false : true;
    }

}

$e = new Endpoint();
$e->setToken($_POST['token']); // change to an MVC design rather than post methods
if($e->isToken()) {
    // API logic (ie, return action related to that token)
}
```

Or see a [working example](https://3v4l.org/i20oX) of this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using SSL and all my queries use prepared statements. Sorry my question is rather unclear; the code posted is one point of the authentication process. In my actual code the function is called verifyAccessToken($AccessToken) where $AccessToken is a self contained JWT. My concern was some kind of PHP code injection or something I can't imagine being used to skip an if block.

Comment: `verifyAccesstoken()` should simply check if the token exists in the database, nothing more or less so there would be no **hack** @kemika